# WebView integration

Tags: cocoa, webkit

I am wondering how to integrate a WebView in a cocoa application:
- How to call javascript function from cocoa in the WebView
- How to handle in cocoa the click in a link inside the WebView
...

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is no NSWebView in cocoa, it's called UIWebView on the iphone and WebView on Mac.

If you want to simply load a page with the webview, create an NSURLRequest (using NSURL) then call `- (void)loadRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request`

If you want to use javascript functions, just make an NSString containing your script, then call `- (NSString*)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script`.

I don't fully understand why you want to handle a click inside the webview... If you want to detect a redirect, there is a delegate method that can help you:

`- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType`